# Error starting build - Android build failing on App Center

Tags: android, flutter, build-pipeline, appcenter

My AppCenter Android build pipeline started failing all of a sudden. Not much information other than **"Error starting build"** title and "Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings." as body. Just FYI, the android project was generated using Flutter.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have contacted App Center support and they replied:

"For now, there is a workaround, on the App Center portal, please go to your application config, without making any change, could you please click on Save and Build".

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As per Marcio,

Go into the App > Build > Branch > Configuration
[image]

And then just click Save (without making changes)
[image]